# How to access a method in the context through unit of work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

If I have the following Context :

```
public partial class HRMainDataCTX : DbContext
{
    public HRMainDataCTX()
        : base("name=HRMainDataCTX")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

  //DbSets
    public virtual int SEARCHEMPLOYEE(Nullable<decimal> p_EMP_NUM, string p_EMP_NAME)
    {
        var p_EMP_NUMParameter = p_EMP_NUM.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("P_EMP_NUM", p_EMP_NUM) :
            new ObjectParameter("P_EMP_NUM", typeof(decimal));

        var p_EMP_NAMEParameter = p_EMP_NAME != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("P_EMP_NAME", p_EMP_NAME) :
            new ObjectParameter("P_EMP_NAME", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SEARCHEMPLOYEE", p_EMP_NUMParameter, p_EMP_NAMEParameter);
    }
}
```

Now i implement Unit of work like this :

```
public class HRCTX : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HRMainDataCTX _context;

    public HRCTX()
    {
        _context = new HRMainDataCTX();
    }

    public HRCTX(HRMainDataCTX context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public HRMainDataCTX Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

I don't know how to access the method (stored procedure) `SEARCHEMPLOYEE` through UOW in my code behind.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and bounty won't help us to answer it as it is

Comment: @Evk : Could you write what's specifically unclear about my question ! and i 'll illustrate it .

Comment: You didn't comment that answer below by bassfader. So if it does not answer your question, can you clarify why? There are valid points about you don't actually need any wrapper, since DbContext already follows unit of work pattern.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare - I agree both with the EvK and also the with the answer below by bassfader. Also you should show the code that actually makes use  of your UoW code so you can illustrate why you can't access the method you had created.

Comment: @Evk   i add a bounty to my question, so that I could get more answers and more ideas .using (repo & UOW) with EF has a lot of debates considering the DbContext -->UOW &DbSets-->repositories.. And i have asked this question before on SOF ..my question is so specific about how to access a method in DbContext through UOW in my code behind .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, in your case you would simply add another "Proxy-Method" for this method to your `HRCTX` proxy / UOW class, or - since `HRCTX` provides access to its underlying context - call it directly on the context like this:

```
HRCTX uow = new HRCTX(someContext);
uow.Context.SEARCHEMPLOYEE(123, "123");
```

But I also wanted to emphasize that the `DbContext` already represents a Unit of Work pattern (combined with a Repository pattern, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)). You are basically creating a proxy for your context, which - as far as I can see in this example - adds no further benefits or functionality, so I'd suggest to at least think about directly using your `HRMainDataCTX` and possibly getting rid of the `HRCTX` class.

Comment: then i have to add a reference to my DAL.dll to access the context and this's make the `UOW` nonsense

Comment: `the type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. you must add a reference`

Comment: One of your `HRCTX` class public constructors takes a `HRMainDataCTX` as a parameter, so you already need to reference your DAL.dll. I agree with @bassfader: with just the code you provided I can't see any advantage over using your DbContext directly. The two proposed approaches are the only alternatives I can think of.

Comment: I want to wrap my `dbcontext` so that no one need to add a reference to `EF` or `DAL` in the UI application.(abstraction layer around my dbcontext)

Comment: That's not what you have though... If you want to abstract away something, you need to define the abstraction in a different library, and add reference to that library only. That library should not mention dbContext, even in constructor parameters, anything that is public should be unaware of the dbContext. Anyway, this is a different question and answer conversation.

Answer (score 8):

You may need to implement repositories along with your Unit Of work pattern if you want to encapsulate your DbContext and your business logic. ([As suggested in the AspNet guidelines](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application))

In a generic manner, your unit of work can handle repositories like this:

```
public class HRCTX : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HRMainDataCTX _context;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> Repositories { get; set; }


    public HRCTX()
    {
        _context = new HRMainDataCTX();
        this.Repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }


    //Get and add a repository to the dictionary if ot does not exist
    public IRepository<TEntity> GetNonGenericRepository<TEntity, TRepository>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (this.Repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TRepository)))
        {
            return this.Repositories[typeof(TRepository)] as IRepository<TEntity>;
        }
        var repoType = typeof(TRepository);
        var constructorInfo = repoType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(DbContext)});
        IRepository<TEntity> repository = (IRepository<TEntity>) constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { this._context});
        this.Repositories.Add(typeof(TRepository), repository);
        return repository;
    }

 public IRepository<TEntity> GetGenericRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity :     class
    {
        if (this.Repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
        {
            return this.Repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;
        }

        IRepository<TEntity> repository = new Repository<TEntity>(this._context);
        this.Repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);
        return repository;
    }


}
```

The interface and base class of your repositories:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> match);
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
       this.Context = context;
    }
    public TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> match)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(match);
    }
}
```

Now is the part where you clearly encapsulate your business logic:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>
{

    public EmployeeRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {

    }
    public override Employee Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> match)
    {
        // You can either use the base class method or implement your custom logic
    }

    //This is where you encapsulate your business logic
     public Employee FindSpecific(Nullable<decimal> employeeNum, string employeeName){
         return this.Context.SEARCHEMPLOYEE(employeeNum, employeeName);
     }
}
```

Then you can use your Unit Of Work to access you business logic in a domain driven design way.

```
HRCTX unitOfWork= new HRCTX(dbContext);
unitOfWork.GetNonGenericRepository<Employee, EmployeeRepository>().FindSpecific(1337,"1337");
```

It can seem to be too much for what you expected as an answer but I think you need to structure your application that way if you don't want to expose you DbContext / Dal directly.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

This webpage documents exactly how to accomplish your goal.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application